# Including asterisks (*) in Circle CI environment variable causes strange side effects in the value of the environment variable

Tags: go, circleci

I have a cron schedule in an Circle CI environment variable, lets call it `CRON_SCHEDULE` to be used within a Go application. Let's say the desired schedule string is `0 15 13 * * *`, for every day exactly 1:15:00 PM, i.e. 13:15:00

The cron wasn't firing and I went to investigate. When I log out `CRON_SCHEDULE` from within the Go application, I get the first three numbers correctly, but instead of the three "*" I see instead the contents of the application files itself:

`my_app docker-compose.yml Dockerfile go.mod go.sum main.go README.md tests utils`

To be clear, this is the full exact output from `fmt.Print(os.Getenv("CRON_SCHEDULE"))`:

```
0 15 13 my_app docker-compose.yml Dockerfile go.mod go.sum main.go README.md tests utils my_app docker-compose.yml Dockerfile go.mod go.sum main.go README.md tests utils my_app docker-compose.yml Dockerfile go.mod go.sum main.go README.md tests utils
```

Very strange!

Does `*` within a Circle CI variable have a special meaning? If so, how can I escape this properly? Or is this instead a Docker quirk (running the Go app from a docker container) and `*` is being printed as the files? No idea what is going on right now!

My current guess is that due to bash shell escaping fun, that when you have the `*` character in an environment variable, they're injected incorrectly into the container / application environment.

EDIT: I can confirm trying to escape these characters removes this 'bug'. However then of course the cron library still can't understand `0 15 13 \* \* \*`!

Comment: How do you set the environment variable?

Comment: `echo CRON_SCHEDULE=${CRON_SCHEDULE} >> .env`

Answer (score 1):

Zeke's question pointed me in the right direction. Apparently, you need to escape the environment injection if you have `*` characters (and perhaps there are others!) in your Circle CI environment files. Appending to my .env file with:

```bash
echo CRON_SCHEDULE="${CRON_SCHEDULE}" >> .env
```

Resolved the issue.